# I've been trying to set this button to the bottom left of the screen. Can anyone find me a better way or suggest a fix to this error?

Tags: android, authentication, button, android-jetpack-compose

```
@Composable
fun LoginForm() {
    var username by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    // Store the state of the bottom sheet
    var bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            // The weight modifier is added to expand the height of the Box to fill the remaining height of the Column
            // This is necessary to push the buttons to the bottom of the screen
        }

        Box(  modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
        )

         {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch { bottomSheetState.show() }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text("Login")
            }
        }

    // Define the bottom sheet content
        ModalBottomSheetLayout(
            sheetContent = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = username,
                        onValueChange = { username = it },
                        label = { Text("Username") },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = password,
                        onValueChange = { password = it },
                        label = { Text("Password") },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    Button(
                        onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { bottomSheetState.hide() } },
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.End)
                    ) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                }
            },
            sheetState = bottomSheetState,
            sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp)
        ) {
            // This composable is the "background" that will be visible when the bottom sheet is open
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
            ) {
                // Add any content you want to show in the background here
            }
        }


    }


}
```

This is for a login screen for an app.

This is the error I have been getting : `"Type mismatch: inferred type is Alignment but Alignment.Horizontal was expected"`

I have been changing the `Alignment.BottomEnd` in the box layout for the Login button but nothing works.
I wanted to set the button to the bottom left end of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ColumnScope` the `align` modifier requires a  `Alignment.Horizontal` parameter.

In you case just use:

```
Box(  
   modifier = Modifier
      .fillMaxWidth()
      .background(Yellow), //it is not neeeded
   contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart,
)
```

Otherwise you can avoid the 1st `Box` using:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement =  Arrangement.Bottom
) {

    Box(  modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
    )

}
```

[image]